# Positioning nested divs

Tags: html, css

I am trying to position divs nested within a centred wrapper so that they don't move when I adjust the size of a browser. The idea is similar to the Facebook homepage where all the divs stay centred and don't move relative to each other when the page is made bigger.

All of my divs are nested in this:

```
#header {
    width: 750px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    }
```

What do I have to do to position the divs within? Is it something to do with positioning?

Sorry this is a bit of a vague explanation, please do ask for clarification!

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably have a clearfix class for that container div (See http://www.positioniseverything.net/easyclearing.html)

As for the inner DIVs, `float: left;` and an explicitly defined width is all you need to have them appear side by side.

Comment: When I set the inner divs to float left they don't move which is what I want. Is there a way to position them elsewhere with the same effect?

Edit: Oh, I was using top instead of margin-top. Not to worry!

Comment: One final thing - how do I centre a div within a div?

Comment: `margin: 0px auto;` will center a div within a div provided a width is specified.

Answer (score 1):

As a rule of thumb: Don't use `position: absolute`. It is rarely the best way to achieve a layout effect.

If you do use absolute positioning, then set `position: relative` on the *container* so that it establishing a new positioning context and elements are positioned relative to its edges instead of the window.

```
#header {
    width: 750px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I used to have the same problem, 
I fixed it by using the attr :

style='min-width:970px;'

i hope it helps